# AWS RDS : Relation between a select/insert query and read/write operations (count/s)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I am trying to read/write data from my AWS RDS instance. When I try to insert around 1000 different data, I get around 100 write operations/second. However when I try to select around 1000 unique data, it just gives me 1 read operations/second.

But I would want to know a scenario where the application would result in a lot of read operations/second. Someone please help !!

Comment: which RDS (postgres, mysql, aurora) ?

Comment: it's AWS-RDS MySQL instance!

Answer (score 1):

These operations are disk operations, not DB engine related. You can read more about RDS metrics dimensions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html

Why do you get such a result? Depends on the RDS engine underneath how it handles disk writing/ reading, caching, memory handling. I suspect it might be related to the fact that some operations are cached in memory first, and flushed every N queries/M seconds, and so on.

Comment: Does AWS have a word about how frequent the data are cached? And is there a way to get read operations proportional to the number of unique select statements ? I want to get around a 1000 read operations (for the purpose of my Research work).

Comment: It is not an AWS feature but MySQL, query can use different number of IO ops depending on indices, optimization, engine used (InnoDB vs MyIsam), transactions and so on. There are so many moving parts that there is not straight answer. If it is possible you should change your research constraints from disk IO ops to queries/s (if it is possible at all).